# How <style>...</style> is linked/works in angular material design (links provided)?

Tags: angularjs

Please look at [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

When you right click the words "Basic usage"(seen at top of the page, first block), you can see below html:

```
<md-toolbar class="demo-toolbar md-primary">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h3 class="ng-binding">Basic Usage</h3>
    <!-- ...other html -->
```

And when you select "md-toolbar" from above code in elements panel, it will show that it has background color of some blue. And it shows style source as

```
<style>...</style>.
```

When you click it, will show it like(click and see please). But generally, it either gives filename.css or says index if css is embedded in html file. But this seems different.

So, my question is there anything "angular/material" with it. Whats going on here ?

Comment: It does look like that `<style>...</style>` has `class="ng-binding"` on it, but that's as much as I can ascertain currently.

Comment: I saw it too but didnt understand more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Theme/Under The Hood docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/05_under_the_hood)

> Each registered theme results in 16 **`<style>`** tags being generated.

It's their way of translating the `$mdThemingProvider` config from javascript to css